# String splitting produces different results than expected

Tags: c#, string, split

[image]

it returns not what i expected.
i expected something like:

ab
cab
ab

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

don't do .ToCharArray()

it will split \r then \n

that why you have empty value

something like this should work

```
var aa = ("a" & Environment.NewLine & "b" & Environment.NewLine & "c").Split(New String[] {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 6):

Since you are splitting on "\r" and "n", `String.Split` extracts the empty string from "\r\n".

Take a look at `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` or use `new String[] { "\r\n" }` instead of `"\r\n".ToCharArray()`.

Answer (score 1):

You just splitting the string using `\r` or `\n` as delimiters, not the `\r\n` together.

Answer (score 1):

Environment.NewLine is probably the way to go but if not this works

```
var ab = "a\r\nb\r\nc";
var abs = ab.Split(new[]{"\r\n"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 0):

This option also works,
   string [] b = Regex.Split(abc, "\r\n");

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that the string char sequence you provide to the Split method is a list of delimiter characters, not a single delimiter madeof several characters.

In your case, Split consider the '\r' and '\n' characters as delimiters. So when it encounters the '\r\n' sequence, it returns the string between those 2 delimiters, an empty string.